# Contour without float artifacts

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, contour

I linearly interpolate and after that contour data. For calculations **I use float type because I do not know how many decimals will be in input data**. Sometimes it might be no decimals, sometimes one or over 10.

Unfortunately **because of using float after interpolation and contouring of same values I get unwanted artifacts**. How can I fix my code to not produce contour artifacts where there should not be any?

Simple code example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

interval_in = np.linspace(1, 100, 10)
interval_out = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
xin, yin = np.meshgrid(interval_in, interval_in)
zin = np.ones((10, 10))*10
xout, yout = np.meshgrid(interval_out, interval_out)
zout = griddata((xin.flatten(),yin.flatten()),zin.flatten(),(xout,yout),method='linear')

contours = plt.contour(xout, yout, zout, levels=[10])
plt.show()
```

[image: Contour artifacts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your example the `zout` should be all 10. but actually varies between 9.9999999999999982 and 10.000000000000002, so contour is trying to plot this. You can use numpy rounding to a given precision,

```
zout_ = np.round_(zout, decimals=3)
contours = plt.contour(xout, yout, zout_, levels=[10])
plt.show()
```

although, if your data has a large range, contour should work correctly...

Comment: Thank you, I am aware it is float problem. Before asking this question I tried the same code with integers and it did not create artifacts at all. My issue is though that I can't simply round to three decimals because in some cases my input values to contour are like 0.0000001 to 0.0000002 and the contour intervals are adequate to it. But thinking about  it again I guess I could use rounding to appropriate number of decimals based on min/max of input values.

Comment: Actually I guess I can simply round to 12 decimal places all the time in my code just to get rid of issue with float. That will do for me. Thank you.